# How to get the wordpress archive title? Is their any function for checking the title of current page displayed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner in PHP!

I am using [Free Kadance theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/kadence/) on WordPress.

In the **Theme customization option >> Homepage Settings >> we can toggle the title ON or OFF.**

If we **toggle the title ON** it will display the title of the website on homepage with the latest posts. I like to display the page title along with some description text on that home page. After sometime of analysis inside WordPress Theme editor.

On WordPress Theme editor >> template-parts >> archive-title >>title.php

There is a section of php code

```
elseif ( is_archive() || is_home() ) {
the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title archive-title">', '</h1>' );
}
```

This section of code is responsible for printing the header text that we **toggle ON**.

Is there some way to get the text which is printed by function: **the_archive_title(  )**

If I can get that text to a variable, then I can check that statement to the title string and if both are equal I could execute desired php file.

Somebody please help!

I tried

```
      elseif ( is_archive() || is_home() ) {
      the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title archive-title">', '</h1>' );
      
      //custom code
         $title_var_to_check = get_the_archive_title();
         echo title_var_to_check;
         if(title_var_to_check == "string to check"){
         ?>
         <p>Checking text </p>
         <?php
         }
     //custom code
     }
```

Result : It worked partially! But every Archive page displayed a text "title_var_to_check" under it.

Comment: You need add $ to title_var_to_check => echo $title_var_to_check;

Comment:  Thanks, I didn't notice that! Now it worked

Comment: I changed if(title_var_to_check == "string to check") => if($title_var_to_check == "string to check") and it worked. Now I can add custom php script inside that if statement to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add $ to title_var_to_check

```
echo $title_var_to_check;
```

and

```
if($title_var_to_check == "string to check"){
```